# Ansible selectattr + map + list returns empty result

Tags: loops, dictionary, filter, ansible

I've been reading and searching a lot and cannot overcome this issue. Can you please help ?

With the content below, I need to extract the attribute "ipAddress" and push to a list. Actual data is a dict of objects such as "host01" but for the example I reduced the data to one host.

```
    {
        "host01": {
            "fqdn": "host01.mydomain",
            "interface": {
                "Bundle-Ether1001": {
                    "ipAddress": "10.20.30.41",
                    "subnetMask": "255.255.255.252"
                },
                "Bundle-Ether1002": {
                    "ipAddress": "10.20.30.45",
                    "subnetMask": "255.255.255.252"
                }
            },
            "timestamp": 1545420334
        }
}
```

My playbook goes as follows:

```
---
- name : myplaybook 
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    myjson: "{{ lookup('file', 'api.json') | from_json }}"


  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{myjson}}"

    - name: debugallip
      when: item.value.interface is defined
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item | selectattr('ipAddress', 'defined') | map('value.ipAddress') | list }}"
      with_dict: "{{ myjson }}"
```

Which returns an empty list ? :(

TASK [debugallip] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': {u'interface': {u'Bundle-Ether1001': {u'subnetMask': u'255.255.255.252', u'ipAddress': u'10.20.30.41'}, u'Bundle-Ether1002': {u'subnetMask': u'255.255.255.252', u'ipAddress': u'10.20.30.45'}}, u'timestamp': 1545420334, u'fqdn': u'host01.mydomain'}, 'key': u'host01'}) => {
    **"msg": []**
}

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to use json_query

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value.interface | dict2items | json_query('[].value.ipAddress') }}"
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, well I tried this too and I thought it was ugly, but at least it worked for me. My solution would produce a list of lists and with some additional steps I could finally get something to work with. Here's what I had

 mylist: "{{ mylist + [item | json_query('value.interface.*.ipAddress')] }}"
      with_dict: "{{ myjson }}"

After reviewing your solution & Matthew's solution, it became clear to my I have to treat the list of interfaces as an array ...

Comment: `mylist: "{{ mylist + [item | json_query('value.interface.*.ipAddress')] }}" with_dict: "{{ myjson }}"`

Answer (score 1):

The `selectattr` filter is incorrect, as the `ipAddress` is buried down in the structure, and not at the top-level of ... well, *anything* in your particular setup. One can very easily see the shape of `item` in the task output, so I have no idea why you would assume any other shape, but here we are. Your invocation of `map` is incorrect, too, since there is no such filter as `value.ipAddress`, which only would have actually exploded if your `selectattr` had been correct.

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ item.value.interface | dict2items | map(attribute="value.ipAddress") | select("defined") }}'
  with_dict: '{{ myjson }}'
```

If you want all the `ipAddress` values buried in the `host.interface` structure, you'll need to essentially do *another* `with_dict` loop over the `host.interface` dict, which is what `dict2items` does. Then, you can save yourself some copy-pasta by going ahead and extracting `.ipAddress`, with the risk that it is not defined, and then toss out the undefined ones at the end

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think somehow I wouldn't accept that the list of json objects is in fact an array. Do you suggest that my data structure is not well-formed ? If so, I'd like to learn so if you have recommendations I'm open to it. Finally, thanks for the explanations and for giving me a working example. I'll build from it.

Comment: in fact, I'd more than interested to see how to loop in a loop (nested loop ?) I tried, oh I tried ... I just don't see it. Did I mention I've been using Ansible for less than a month ?